# Install Python3.10 on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3, 23.04

I've tried to install python3.10 alongside with native python3.11, on Ubuntu 23.04, but looks like it's not available.

```
mika@system:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3.10
Hit:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Get:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:3 https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb stable InRelease          
Get:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease [109 kB] 
Fetched 317 kB in 1s (295 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.10 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.10' has no installation candidate
```

I've tried to use deadsnakes, but they [don't have](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) the Release file for current Ubuntu version. Executing `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` confirms that.

Is it possible to install python3.10 on Ubuntu 23.04?

Comment: Don't change the default python version. You might end up destroying Ubuntu. Instead, use Miniconda/Anaconda to create a virtual environment.

Comment: Same issue here. Real bummer. I now have python3.9 and 3.11 and Ubuntu 23.04, and a lot of projects on python3.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed with [compiling python from source](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/10/compile-install-python-3-10-ubuntu/) + [adding the usr/local/bin to PATH and updating alternatives for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt).

Comment: Deadsnakes doesn't offer Python 3.10 for Ubuntu 23.04, but you should be able to get Python 3.11 if that works. If this is for something that is explicitly looking for Python 3.10, yes, you'll have to compile from source. Here's a nice article explaining how to do that for anyone who stumbles across this: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-python-on-ubuntu-linux-system/?expand_article=1

Comment: Don't change the default python version. You might end up destroying Ubuntu. Instead, use Miniconda/Anaconda to create a virtual environment.

Comment: Worked for me. I installed python 3.10.9 on Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of deadsnakes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/python
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install python3.10
```

Comment: failed with
> E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/python/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.